# Accidentally deleted /usr/bin/python instead of /usr/local/bin/python on OS X/macOS, how to restore?

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I had so many Python installations that it was getting frustrating, so I decided to do a full reinstall. I removed the `/Library/Frameworks/Python.Frameworks/` folder, and meant to remove the `/usr/local/bin/python` folder too, but I accidentally removed the `/usr/bin/python` instead. I don't see any difference, everything seems to be working fine for now, but I've read multiple articles online saying that I should never touch `/usr/bin/python` as OS X uses it and things will break.

I tried Time Machine but there are no viable recovery options. How can I manually "restore" what was deleted? Do I even need to, since everything seems to be working fine for now? I haven't restarted the Mac yet, in fear that things might break.

I believe the exact command I ran was `rm -rf /usr/bin/python*`, and I don't have anything python related in my `/usr/bin/` folder.

I'm running on macOS Mojave 10.14.5

Answer (score 1):

Items can't be recovered when you perform `rm -rf`. However, you can try the following:

`cp /usr/local/bin/python* /usr/bin`

This would copy user local python to usr bin and most probably will bail you out.

Don't worry, nothing will happen to your OS. It should work fine :)

Comment: Yeah, well, the thing is, I didn't realize `/usr/bin/python` was important, so I just shrugged it off and then ran `rm -rf /usr/local/bin/python*` right after. So now I have neither, I only have the ones in `/System` directory, would one of those do?

Comment: I am unsure on what is present under /System. Could you just verify whether it contains some files like -- python, python3.x python3 or similar with python2 version.

If yes, you can very well try to restore the same.

Comment: Yeah there are multiple python2 installations that macOS uses internally, but I managed to find a copy of /usr/bin/python online for my macOS version, everything works now :)

Comment: Perfect! If you found my answer useful and helped you, feel free to upvote it.
Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall Python from it's [website](https://python.org). This would install a fresh copy of Python on your machine.